# IIS 7.5 SMTP E-Mail Queuing when SMTP Server is unavailable

Tags: iis-7.5, smtp

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server running IIS 7.5, that also has the SMTP Server feature installed.

In the IIS Manager, SMTP E-mail is configured to deliver to localhost.

The server barfed yesterday, and was rebooted.  The SMTP Server service didn't start for some reason, and had to be started manually.

Right now all of the directories in \inetpub\mailroot are empty.  I am trying to figure out if any email from IIS (eg, from ASP.NET form processors) got lost during the time the server was booted, but the SMTP Server wasn't running.

So, what does IIS 7.5 do when it is configured to deliver to localhost, and nothing is there accept the email?  Does it get queued somewhere (and where?)  Does it get dropped?

Comment: Just a note, one of the most likely reasons the service didn't start is that it was set to Manual rather than Automatic startup.  Unlike most Windows services, when you install SMTP it defaults to Manual startup mode, and it's pretty common for folks to forget to change it and then have SMTP fail when they reboot for patching, etc.

Comment: @phoebus  Thanks.  It actually was set to automatic.  I can't find the  entries in my history, but I have seen some mention in forums about that service not always starting.  The reboot was due to "bad" server problem, so that could have had something to do with it.